# Curl Error : Failed to connect to <url> port 8444: Connection refused, works in local but not in server

Tags: php, ssl, curl, port, cpanel

I am trying to integrate bank online payment system. For that I need to make handshake with bank server.With crt and key file i have done it in localhost with curl,sending crt and key file to band server while performing handshake and they approved it.But somehow when I upload the project in server it give error "Curl Error : Failed to connect to  port : Connection refused"
, i want to know what might cause this problem, do i need to store crt and key file in specific folder? the website is ssl certified.
my curl code is:

```
$request = <has xml file>
    $twpg_gateway_url = <url>;
    $twpg_cert_file = getcwd().'\wp-content\themes\nikkon\website.com.crt';
    //echo getcwd();exit();
    $twpg_key_file = getcwd().'\wp-content\themes\nikkon\website.key';
    $twpg_key_password = <password>;
    $curl = curl_init();

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)',
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
        CURLOPT_URL => $twpg_gateway_url . '/Exec',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: text/xml'),
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30
    );

    if ($twpg_cert_file != '') {
        $options[CURLOPT_SSLCERT] = $twpg_cert_file;
        $options[CURLOPT_SSLKEY] = $twpg_key_file;
        $options[CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD] = $twpg_key_password;
    }

    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$response)
    {
        echo "Curl Error : " . curl_error($curl);
    }
    curl_close($curl);

    return $response;
```

Comment: Please edit the question and ask more specific things like where is your server hosted, what framework are you using, what do you mean by 'does not work'. Do you get an error?

Comment: @srik i have edited the question

Comment: I expect it is a firewall problem. Is connection to <url>:8444 allowed on the server?

Comment: @jjok im new to this port things, can you help me how do i see this port is allowed and how to make it free in cpanel?

Comment: @SushanShrestha I don't know if you can do that in cPanel. It's probably best to ask your host if it's possible, or look at their documentation.

Comment: @jjok hey thanks, i have told one hosting company to open the port and they did and it works. but in another hosting company i tell them to open port , they say they opened the port but somehow its not working. is there any way or medium to check if the port is open or not in hosting server?

Answer (score 0):

This is a script I use to test if a port is open.

```
try {
    $hostname = isset($_SERVER['argv'][1])? $_SERVER['argv'][1]: 'localhost';
    $port = isset($_SERVER['argv'][2])? $_SERVER['argv'][2]: 80;

    printf(' ? Attempting to connect to: %s:%u', $hostname, $port);

    if(@fsockopen($hostname, $port, $code, $message, 5) === false) {
        throw new RuntimeException($message, $code);
    }

    printf("\r:) Successfully connected to: %s:%u", $hostname, $port);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    printf("\nError: %u - %s", $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
    exit(1);
}
```

Run it like this from the command line `php socket-test.php example.com 25`.
Or you could modify it to work in a web browser.